# How do I target specific labels with Javascript? (i.e. not using "contains")

Tags: javascript

Apologies in advance, I have zero programming knowledge.

So my company just bought some software that includes a checkout function. For some reason, the checkout page does not by default highlight which fields are mandatory vs optional in order to complete checkout.

My boss has asked to me highlight the mandatory fields, which can be done through javascript. Except I don't know javascript.

The support guy helped me out, and I've been able to do most of it using the 'contains' function, like this:

```
$('.page-checkout label:contains(Country)').after(' <span class="required-text" style="color:red">* Required</span>');
```

But, I have some fields don't have a unique enough label for the contains function to only highlight what I need (e.g. I want to highlight the mandatory "address" field, but not the optional "address 2" field).

How do I only target the "address" field without also hitting the "address 2" field?

Comment: You need to provide the rendered html for anyone to really help you. The function you are using targets specific elements based upon class and label contents. In general, if you want to target specific elements you should add a css class to those elements and then you would just need to select off class name (like the first element in your query `.page-checkout`).

Comment: Targeting parts of the page by *content* is not a great idea. The content may change because somebody thinks of a better wording for something, or abbreviations, or of course if the page is translated to another language. Metadata on the elements (classes, most commonly) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (i.e. not using "contains")

Or perhaps using "not contains"?

You could amend the `:contains(Address)` with a `:not(:contains(2))`.  For example:

```js
$('.page-checkout label:contains(Address):not(:contains(2))').after(' <span class="required-text" style="color:red">* Required</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-checkout">
  <label for="address">Address</label>
  <input id="address">
  <label for="address2">Address 2</label>
  <input id="address2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe a more elegant way:

```js
//Labels to search for 
const aSearch = ["Country", "Adress", "Firstname"];

//Create a new CSS Class and append to head
$( "<style>.my-required-class:after { color: #f00; content: '* Required'; }</style>" ).appendTo("head");
   

//Search for labels and...
for (let i = 0; i < aSearch.length; i++) {
  $(".page-checkout label").filter(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === aSearch[i]) {
      //... add new class
      $(this).addClass("my-required-class");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-checkout">
  <label for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
  <input id="Firstname" />
  <br/>
  <label for="Lastname">Lastname</label>
  <input id="Lastname" />
  <br/>
  <label for="Country">Country</label>
  <input id="Country" />
  <br/>
  <label for="Adress">Adress</label><br/>
  <input id="Adress" />
  <br/>
  <label for="Adress-2">Adress 2</label><br/>
  <input id="Adress-2" />
</div>
```